# cURL makes invalid bencoding when downloading torrents from torcache

Tags: windows, curl, bencoding

The title says it all. I realize that a similar question has been asked at https://askubuntu.com/questions/307566/wget-and-curl-somehow-modifying-bencode-file-when-downloading/310507#310507 but I don't think the same solution works, because I have tried to unzip the file using 7zip, and also Gzip for windows (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm). Both claim the file to be of wrong format. Renaming it's extension to .gz or .zip doesn't help either. The --compressed attribute is no help as well. So, my guess is something's changed on the torcache site. I've tried using the user-agent as well, to no avail.

In a related issue, I guess, when I try downloading from the https site, I recieve "curl: (52) Empty reply from server". Only http works, and that gives me invalid bencoding. When I enter the URL on my browser, the torrent file downloads all by itself.

The command I'm entering is as follows:

`curl -O http://torcache.net/torrent/006DDC8C407ACCDAF810BCFF41E77299A373296A.torrent`